# How to reset or 'clean' Random

Tags: c#, random, drawing

I'm using a Random in one class to decide which shape to draw, out of three possible shapes, using a switch.

After the shape is determined, I construct a shape with a bunch of random properties using a different instance of Random. Everything works fine, except that, for some reason, the number generated to decide the shape is somehow affecting the randomly generated draw position.

Deciding and creating an instance of the shape (derived from TwoDimShape, see below):

```
private void btnGenerateRandShapes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)numRandShapes.Value; i++) {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int tmp = rnd.Next(0, 3);
            switch (tmp) {
                case 0:
                    Circle circle = new Circle(drawArea);
                    circle.Draw();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Triangle triangle = new Triangle(drawArea);
                    triangle.Draw();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(drawArea);
                    rectangle.Draw();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Randomizing the shapes properties in base class:

```
public TwoDimShape(Graphics drawArea) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    this.drawArea = drawArea;
    startPos = new Point(rand.Next(0, MAX_X_POS), rand.Next(0, MAX_Y_POS));
    height = rand.Next(0, MAX_DIM);
    width = rand.Next(0, MAX_DIM);
    lineWidth = rand.Next(MIN_LINE_WIDTH, MAX_LINE_WIDTH);
    outlineColor = Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(0, 255), rand.Next(0, 255), rand.Next(0, 255), rand.Next(0, 255));
    fillColor = Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(0, 255), rand.Next(0, 255), rand.Next(0, 255), rand.Next(0, 255));
    brush = new SolidBrush(fillColor);
    pen = new Pen(outlineColor, lineWidth);
}
```

I'm drawing these shapes in a picturebox. For some reason, circles are drawn on the left third of the picturebox, triangles in the middle third, and rectangles on the right third.

If put the shape construction in a different case in the switch, it changes which third they are drawn in.

This is leading me to believe that the random number generated in btnGenerateShapes_Click is effecting the number generated in the TwoDimShapes constructor.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it? Again, the two instance of Random used are in different classes, so why is one affecting the other?

Answer (score 3):

You are instantiating the random instance in a loop. This will cause it to have the same seed for several iterations since the default seed is time-based without making distinctions on a lower level.

Instantiate it outside the loop and perhaps add some fancy things like `ThreadLocal` to avoid this.